# Accessing selected data in dropdown list

Tags: java, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to get selected data from dropdown list but i could not . With this code , i am getting undefined as an selected value.

`(change)="selectChangeHandler($event)"` i am trying to get value with this .

```html
    <label class="badge">From</label>
        <select  formControlName="depature-form" class="form-control" (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)" >
          <option *ngFor="let val of airportOptions" [value]="val.id">{{val.airportName}}</option>
        </select>
```

```
    import {Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {FlightService} from "../../services/shared/flight.service";
    import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
    import {TicketService} from "../../services/shared/ticket.service";
    import {AirportService} from "../../services/shared/airport.service";

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-flight',
      templateUrl: './flight.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./flight.component.css']
    })
    export class FlightComponent implements OnInit {

      // route parameter options
      selectedDay: string='';
      // Dropdown values
      airportOptions = [];

      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
                  private flightService : FlightService,
                  private ticketService: TicketService,
                  private airportService : AirportService,
      ) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.loadAirports();
      }
      private loadAirports() {
        this.airportService.getAll().subscribe(response => {
          this.airportOptions = response;
        })
      }
      selectChangeHandler(event : any ) {
        this.selectedDay = event.target.value;
        console.log(this.selectedDay);
      }
    }
```

I was expecting selected data from dropdown list but actual output undefined.

Comment: How about changing `[value]="val.id"` to `value="{{val.id}}"`

Answer (score 0):

I found the way .It was returning null and i found index and put it to array.

```
selectChangeHandler(event : any ) {
    this.selectedDay = event.target.value;
    var selectedindex=event.target.selectedIndex;

    console.log(this.airportOptions[event.target.selectedIndex]);
  }
```